# iOS WKWebView won't access iPhone XR camera

Tags: xcode, swiftui, wkwebview, ios13, wkwebviewconfiguration

I created an iOS WebView app and wanted to display the following website: https://qrcodescan.in/ within this app through WkWebView in fullscreen. Opening it up on safari works perfectly fine and before I can use it I get the message regarding granting camera access.

Opening the same URL up on my app though won't give me any pop up asking for camera permission and therefore the app is not usable. The console show this message: *Connection to daemon was invalidated.*

I even asked someone to look for the problem and he deployed the same project without any configuration on his iPhone 8 running iOS 13.5.1 and it works perfectly fine. I use an iPhone XR and iOS 13.5.1 as well but it seems. like that I can't get any camera access.

Is there anyone who eventually knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try asking for camera permission before the web view is created in your app. Request these permissions as if your app was using the camera, not the web view. The web view should then be able to request permission.